# Error in Android Tutorial with sendMessage (view; View) - App Basics, starts another activity

Tags: android, button, sendmessage

When I try to change the property of the Button (onClick) no the drop downlist is empty and I receive errors when adding the `sendMessage (view; View)` Method. See below the assigment:

*In the file `app > java > com.example.myfirstapp > MainActivity`, add the sendMessage() method stub as shown below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  }
  /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
  fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    // Do something in response to button
  }
}
```

You may see an error because Android Studio cannot resolve the View class used as the method argument. So click to place your cursor on the View declaration, and then perform a Quick Fix by pressing Alt + Enter (or Option + Enter on Mac). (If a menu appears, select Import class.)

Now return to the `activity_main.xml` file to call this method from the button:
Click to select the button in the Layout Editor.
In the Attributes window, locate the onClick property and select sendMessage [MainActivity] from the drop-down list **(THIS DOES NOT APPEAR??).**
Now when the button is tapped, the system calls the sendMessage() method.*

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please. What do you try to archive? what is the concrete error message? what have you try to solve it by yourself?

Comment: I'm new to android and just follow the tutorial. The tutorial describes that after placing the statement (fun sendMessage(view: View)) in mainActivity section,  I should be able to see it in the drop down box, when I would like to change the button attribute (onClick property). But when I click on the dropdown box  I only get the option "NONE". I don't see the sendMessage method in the dropdown box. According to the tutorial I should be able to select the method in the dropdown box which is not possible. Is that because of error of the fun sendMessage(view: View)  in the mainActivity section?

Comment: I used the quick fixed option to resolve the error in caused by the "fun sendMessage(view: View) by using OPTION+ENTER in the mainActivity section, on my Mac. But the error remains. I assume that this is the reason that I can't choose the method for the Button -onClick property? Can you help me to solve the problem in the mainActivity section so that i can choose this method in the onClick property dropdown list please?

Answer (score 1):

For those that come back to this, try switching to JAVA instructions rather than KOTLIN, this then worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the sendMessage function in Jave syntax and that's it

Try replacing the sendMessage with the code below and then you should be able to view the senMessage

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
}
```

Comment: I suppose you forgot to pass a function's body :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with java version of the tutorial. (That's how I found this thread.) Just in case someone else runs in this problem:

1. I wrote a "system.out.print("Tadaa!")" //a filler code inside the sendMessage method.
2. crtl + s (=save the file)
3. try clicking some other area in layout editor and then return to the button-widget again. You should be able to find the sendMessage in onClick-attribute. If not, maybe saving the project, closing it and opening it again would help?